# How to set index to an existing dataframe in the form of cartesian product?

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a list. I want to set_index of dataframe in the form of a cartesian product of list values with dataframe i.e

```
li = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
```

I want the resulting dataframe to be like

```
   0  1  2
A  0  0  0
A  1  1  1
A  2  2  2
B  0  0  0
B  1  1  1
B  2  2  2
```

How can I do this?
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`pd.concat` with `keys` argument

```
pd.concat([df] * len(li), keys=li) 

     0  1  2
A 0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1
  2  2  2  2
B 0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1
  2  2  2  2
```

---

To replicate your output exactly:

```
pd.concat([df] * len(li), keys=li).reset_index(1, drop=True)

   0  1  2
A  0  0  0
A  1  1  1
A  2  2  2
B  0  0  0
B  1  1  1
B  2  2  2
```

---

**Option 2**
`np.tile` and `np.repeat`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df, [len(li), 1]), np.repeat(li, len(df)), df.columns)

   0  1  2
A  0  0  0
A  1  1  1
A  2  2  2
B  0  0  0
B  1  1  1
B  2  2  2
```

Comment: I tried pd.concat but not in this way. This is really nice.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([li, df.index])
df = df.reindex(mux, level=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df)
   0  1  2
A  0  0  0
A  1  1  1
A  2  2  2
B  0  0  0
B  1  1  1
B  2  2  2
```

Comment: I missed the reindex part. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can using .

```
li = [['A','B']]
df['New']=li*len(df)
df.set_index([0,1,2])['New'].apply(pd.Series).stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:'keys'})\
     .reset_index().drop('level_3',1).sort_values('keys')

Out[698]: 
   0  1  2 keys
0  0  0  0    A
2  1  1  1    A
4  2  2  2    A
1  0  0  0    B
3  1  1  1    B
5  2  2  2    B
```

Comment: You should know the unlist ~ :)

Comment: Wen to be honest I first thought this one. And swear to God I didn't copy your solution to some earlier questions. And this is a possibility too with a bit of hard work.

Comment: @Bharathshetty, it is ok ~ i also learn it from others ~ :) happy coding